# Updating a value within a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update the `department` of `bob` to `Human Resources`. I was under the impression from my readings and research that you just needed to rename the value within the key as I have done within my code but I keep getting an Assertion error. Any tips?

```
directory= [{'firstName': "bob", 'department': "Accounting", 'salary': 50000}, {'firstName': "alice", 'department': "Marketing", 'salary': 100000}]
```

#My Code

```
directory['department'] = 'Human Resources'
```

Comment: `directory` is a ***list*** of dicts, not a ***dict***. You first need to find the dict with `firstName == "bob"` in the list, and then update its `department`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```py
directory= [{'firstName':"bob",'department':"Accounting",'salary':50000},{'firstName':"alice",'department':"Marketing",'salary':100000}]

for d in directory:
   if 'firstName' in d and d['firstName'] == 'bob':
      d['department'] = 'Human Resources'
      break

print(directory) # [{'firstName': 'bob', 'salary': 50000, 'department': 'Human Resources'}, {'firstName': 'alice', 'salary': 100000, 'department': 'Marketing'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not actually dealing with a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries. This means you can't directly access the key, you have to access the item in the list.

To fix your current code:

```
 directory[0]['department'] = 'Human resources'
```

Notice the `[0]`.

You can tell this is the data structure because it has square brackets before and after the curly brackets. Eg. `directory =`***`[{ ... }]`***

For future reference, if you would like to look up someone by name, you'll need to iterate through the list and then update the appropriate dictionary.

```py
for entry in directory:
    # We're looking for Bob from accounting, not Bob the auditor. 
    if entry['name'] == 'bob' and entry['department'] == 'Accounting':
       entry['department'] = 'Human Resources'
       # break makes sure that this only happens once.
       break
```

Since `bob` is a relatively common name, you might need to make your name values more unique. `Bob Vila` is more unique than `bob`, meaning you are less likely to address someone you don't mean to.

Of course, if you *know* that you have a unique value for each entry in the directory, then you can convert the whole thing into a dict.

```py
# This is a dictionary comprehension. They're pretty neat.
new_directory = {employee['name']: employee for employee in directory}
new_directorr['bob']['department'] = 'Human resources'
```

On the linked question, the recommendation is a generator expression inside of `next`:

```
try:
    bob = next(employee for employee in directory if employee['name'] == 'bob')
    bob['department'] = 'Human Resources'
except StopIteration: # next will cause a exception if bob cannot be found.
    pass
```

But you should note: the use of `next` with a list comprehension as well as `for...in` the iteration above: both are good ideas in some circumstances, but they will slow down over time as your `directory` gets bigger.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I was getting to that. Gave the easy answer first, then the more specific with the better options.

Comment: And then closed as duplicate? If you think the link doesn't answer this question, don't close as duplicate. If you believe it does but have a better way, post the answer there...

Comment: By the way the last part is not a list-comprehension, it's a generator expression and how is it different than the loops you are doing in your approach?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good point on the generator and the O(n) of the `for` iteration. Answer updated.

I often try to give people a little bit more than "this is a duplicate, go see this other thing here." In this case, the OP clearly missed the fact that this is a list of dictionaries instead of just a dictionary. Going to the other question also does not address the issue of whether that is what they need or how to implement it. As a beginner, does he know when a StopIteration will happen? I'm trying to help in that case.